# Javascript Canvas one item flickering

Tags: javascript, canvas, flicker

I am trying to make to objects move towards each other in Canvas, when they meet and overlap one should then disappear and the other should fall down. Now I got the animation to do that, but one of the items is flickering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas{border:#666 3px solid;}
</style>

</head>
<body onload="draw(530,15); draw1(1,15);">
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
function draw(x,y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, 600, 400);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect (x, y, 70, 50);
    ctx.restore(); 
    x -= 0.5;
 if(x==300)
 {
    return;
 };
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',5);
 };
 
 function draw1(w,e){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(w-1,e-2,600,400);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect (w, e, 70, 50);
    ctx.restore(); 
    w += 1;
 if(w==265)
 {
 w -= 1;
 e +=2;
 };
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw1('+w+','+e+')',10);
};
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Been trying for two days, but can't seem to fix it properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering too many frames per second forcing the browser to present frames. Each time a draw function returns the browser presumes you want to present the frame to the page.

Animations need to be synced to the display refresh rate which for most devices is 60FPS. To do this you have one render loop that handles all the animation. You call this function via `requestAnimationFrame` (RAF) which ensures that the animation stays in sync with the display hardware and browser rendering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas{border:#666 3px solid;}
</style>

</head>
<!-- dont need this <body onload="draw(530,15); draw1(1,15);">-->
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas,ctx,x,y,w,e;
var canvas,ctx,x,y,w,e;
function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 70, 50);
};

function draw1(w, e) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect(w, e, 70, 50);
};

function update(time){  // high precision time passed by RAF when it calls this function
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear all of the canvas
    if(w + 70 >= x){
        e += 2;        
    }else{
        x -= 0.75;
        w += 1;
    };
    draw(x,y);
    draw1(w,e);

    requestAnimationFrame(update)
    // at this point the function exits and the browser presents
    // the canvas bitmap for display
}

function start(){ // set up
    x = 530;
    y = 15;
    w = 1;
    e = 15;
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
window.addEventListener("load",start);
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: This works perfectly, tuned it a bit for my use. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're method of animation is very outdated (ie, the use of `setTimeout`). Instead you should be using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) as demonstrated below. This will give smooth, flicker free animation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas{border:#666 3px solid;}
</style>

</head>
<body onload="requestAnimationFrame(animate);">
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
var x = 530, y = 15;  
function animate(){
  requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(x, y, 600, 400);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
  ctx.fillRect (x, y, 70, 50);
  x -= 0.5;
  if(x==300)
  {
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestID)
  };
}
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

the first 2 parameters of ctx.clearReact in both draw functions should be 0:

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);

This means you clear all canvas.

Comment: Congrats - you just made both items flicker!

Comment: @jamiec, you should recheck before down vote. Run his code to see the problem. and then change to mine to see the solution

Comment: I did. I copied the OP's snippet to a new answer, changed all `clearRect` to 0,0 for the first two params, and ran it. Did *you* check?

Comment: Yep - both flicker now on your jsfiddle too! And in any case, I cant see how clearing the entire canvas from 0,0 is the answer to this question.